# Message sent using invalid number of digits. Please resend using 10 digit number or valid short code android 9230 in android

Tags: android

I am creating application in which we reply to sender of the text message automatically from our android device. I had check that number has only digits not letters for validation but some times while sending message it gives me error as:

Message sent using invalid number of digits. Please resend using 10 digit number or valid short code android

like that how can i avoid number formatting in android.  or is there another way avoid this error. If any one knows solution about this please let me know.

Thank You.
 Vikram

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an issue with a specific mobile operator, not an Android issue?
http://discussion.treocentral.com/palm-pre/189321-9230-message-sent-using-invalid-number-digits.html

Apparently related to ensuring the area code is included when you send a message.